# How to setup DHCP Relay in Debian 8?

Tags: linux, debian

have three VMs. One VM is a DNS and DHCP server, one is a Linux router running Debian 8 and the last VM is a test machine. I am trying to configure the Debian 8 machine as a DHCP relay. I have installed the dhcp relay. Network config are: Line 1: Linux router ip (192.168.1.1) (eth0), this connects to the test computer which is configured to receive IP configuration dynamically. Line 2: Linux router ip (10.0.0.2)(eth1), this connects with the DHCP server (10.0.0.1) DHCP relay does not seem to work because the test machine does not receive an address, instead it uses APIPA. Here is what I have in the `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-relay` file:

```
SERVERS="10.0.0.1"
INTERFACES="eth1
```

"
I get the following error in cmd when I run `ipconfig /renew` Unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Does your router works properly?**

Check if you can ping from server to test machine. If not fix this first!

**Step 2: Configuring DHCP-relay agent**

- Show the configuration of the DHCP server as well to be sure.
- Don't you need to specify both interfaces? The interface from server to router and interface from router to client? So I think you need to put both like this `INTERFACES="eth0 eth1"`.
- Check your " if they are correct in the file (because they are not in your original post above).
- Did you start the isc-dhcp-relay service? (Run `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-relay restart`)

How did you install the "dhcp relay" exactly? I assume you did an install of "isc-dhcp-relay" since you are talking about isc-dhcp-relay file.

It might be interesting to have a look at the logs to see what happens (and more importantly what not). Using wireshark might also give you some answers.

Also I've never used it but since you are on debian I think *dhcp-helper* might be something worth looking at.